# split by regex [tag1=val1] [tag2=val2] [tag3=val3]

Tags: java, regex

I want to split string (can be more pairs)

```
[tag1=val1] [tag2=val2] [tag3=val3]
```

to an array:

```
tag1=val1 
tag2=val2
tag3=val3
...
n
```

there is the regex which works on web regex testing services

```
\[([^\[\]]*)\]
```

but when I try to use it in java I get empty result:

```
"[tag1=val1] [tag2=val2] [tag3=val3]".split("\\[([^\\[\\]]*)\\]"); \\empty
```

Comment: Do not split with that regex, *match* and grab Group 1 value.

Comment: Regex for that would be: `\w+=\w+`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to *split* you'd need to split on the `] [` between tags (that's your delimiter) and strip the leading and trailing bracket. Assuming your list always is in the form you posted, you can try this:

```
String input = "[tag1=val1] [tag2=val2] [tag3=val3]";
String[] tags = input.substring( 1, input.length() - 1 ).split( "\\]\\s*\\[" );
```

Here `substring()` is used to strip the first and last character on the assumption that those are `[` and `]`. Then the result is split on `] [` with any amount of whitespace between the brackets.

However, it might be better to just use your regex and look for the matches between brackets in a loop, as the others have already suggested. Assuming you might want to get tag name and values separately you could use the following expression: `\[(.*?)=(.*?)\]`. That would match as little as possible and collect the tag name into group 1 of the match and the value into group 2.

If you want to make that expression even safer, you could disallow brackets and the equal sign similar your expression, i.e. `\[([^\[\]=]*)=([^\[\]=]*)\]`

Short breakdown:

- `[^\[\]=]` is a negative character class matching anything but `[` , `]` and `=`
- `([^\[\]=]*)` captures a match of arbitrary length of the class above into a group
- `\[([^\[\]=]*)=([^\[\]=]*)\]` matches two groups of your class (see above) separated by `=` and enclosed by `[` and `]`

Answer (score 3):

Your current regex works well if you *match* the strings using `Matcher#find()`:

```
String s = "[tag1=val1] [tag2=val2] [tag3=val3]";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\[([^\\[\\]]*)]");
Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
List<String> results = new ArrayList<>();
while(m.find()) {
    results.add(m.group(1)); // Get Group 1 value only (note you may trim it here)
}
System.out.println(results); // => [tag1=val1, tag2=val2, tag3=val3]
```

See the [online Java demo](https://ideone.com/yz4k7w).

The pattern works indeed:

- `\[` - matches a `[`
- `([^\[\]]*)` - is a capturing group with ID 1 and matches 0+ chars other than `[` and `]` - note that `[` and `]` inside a character class in Java regex must be escaped
- `]` - a literal `]` char (does not have to be escaped outside a character class).

Answer (score 0):

As you want to get the result as a list of Strings the use of String.split seems to be a good solution. Try the following regex:

```
"[tag1=val1] [tag2=val2] [tag3=val3]".split("(?:\\] *)?\\[|\\]$");
```